# Include properties from base class when using Reinforced.Typings framework

Tags: reinforced-typings

I have this class. Notice it inherits from `IdEntity`:

```
[TsClass]
public class UserModel : IdEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is the `IdEntity` class:

```
public class IdEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping that the property `Id` from the base class was exported to the `.ts` file, but this is what I got:

```
export class UserModel
{
    public Name: string;
    public Email: string;
}
```

How can I set `Reinforced.Typings` to include properties from base class? In this case, the property would have an extra property like `public Id: number;`. I tried decorating the `IdEntity` class with `[TsClass]`, but it didn't added the property, it just included the `IdEntity` class in the output.

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you ever find a solution @Felipe?

Comment: No. I wrote my own generator.

Comment: I just figured out the solution - you need to apply the `[TsClass]` attribute to both the parent and child classes and the exported TypeScript classes will maintain the inheritance relationship.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using TsClassAttribute, there should be an argument called FlattenHierarchy that you just need to set to true.

Source: https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/wiki/Configuration-attributes#-tsclass-required

```
[TsClass(FlattenHierarchy = true)]
```